# Any alternative way to get input instead of using bool

Tags: c#

I had a question. Me and my friend working on one program code and but he used bool function true/false. and I am confused in that one. I'm wondering is there any other alternative to get input to make the code clearer. Need a solution for this, please 
thanks.

```
    static bool needToGetInputFromUser;
    static bool isUserEnteredValidInputData = false;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int Choice;

        do
        {
            needToGetInputFromUser = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Please select any of the following options to continue");
            Console.WriteLine("");

            Console.WriteLine("Press1: To Track Customer ");
            Console.WriteLine("Press2 : To track Supplier");
            Choice = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            if (Choice == 1)
            {
                TrackCustomerData();

                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to track Supplier? (Y/N).");
                if (Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine()).ToLower() == "y")
                {
                    TrackSupplierData();
                }
            }
            else if (Choice == 2)
            {
                TrackSupplierData();

                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to track customer? (Y/N).");
                if (Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine()).ToLower() == "y")
                {
                    TrackCustomerData();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please choose correct choice");
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to re-enter choice? (Y/N).");

                if (Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine()).ToLower() == "y")
                {
                    needToGetInputFromUser = true;
                }
            }
    } while (needToGetInputFromUser);
```

Comment: You mean  this part ..ToLower() == "y".. ?

Comment: You can write a function to get the input

Comment: @Edgars no that one. here it is " needToGetInputFromUser = false; " this one

Comment: @ARUN ok .. can you give any example or help in this

Comment: I am assuming the code you left off  } while (needToGetInputFromUser);

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to read an input dynamically, this would be the simplest one. However, you could also use a Form (also a easy way) or a WebPage to read and call the method accordingly. In this case you would have to increase a little bit more of complexity to your code.

Steps:

1. Create a form application
2. Into the form, create a drop-down with two options (customer and supplier).
3. Into the form, create a button, which will call the method according to the selected value from the drop-down.

Good luck

Comment: i'm not using form in this. working on console application

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea

```
bool GetInput(){
  Console.WriteLine("");
 if( Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine()).ToLower() == "y")
    return true;
 else 
    return false;
}
```

i am not much of a console application guy, anybody can edit this

Comment: thanks mate. i think have to changed the Bool to this function to make it clear. im right ?

Answer (score 0):

The do while is a fine way to keep the console repeating until it gets the input it wants. Copy the below code into LinqPad to try it out and make tweaks without messing with your group code. It flows in the manner it looks like you are trying to do.

```
void Main()
{
    var needToGetInputFromUser = false;
    var isUserEnteredValidInputData = false;
    var choice = 0;

    do
    {
        needToGetInputFromUser = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Please select any of the following options to continue");
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Press 1 : To Track Customer ");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 2 : To track Supplier");

        //previous implementation could throw an exception and end program
        //use this for non integer inputs
        if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out choice))
        {
            needToGetInputFromUser = InvalidInput();
        }

        if (choice == 1)
        {
            TrackCustomerData();

            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to track Supplier? (Y/N).");
            if (Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine()).ToLower() == "y")
            {
                TrackSupplierData();
            }
        }
        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            TrackSupplierData();

            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to track Customer? (Y/N).");
            if (Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine()).ToLower() == "y")
            {
                TrackCustomerData();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Integers that are not 1 or 2
            needToGetInputFromUser = InvalidInput();
        }
    } while (needToGetInputFromUser);
}

public bool InvalidInput()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please choose correct choice");
    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to re-enter choice? (Y/N).");

    if (Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine()).ToLower() == "y")
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void TrackCustomerData()
{
    //Some customer data work
    Console.WriteLine("Customer tracked...");
}

public void TrackSupplierData()
{
    //come supllier data work
    Console.WriteLine("Supplier tracked...");
}
```

Comment: @cubicke.Jockey The thing is he used "needToGetInputFromUser = false;" in whole of the code. Now m confused where do I use your idea to get rid of this bool

Comment: You don't need to get rid of it. He initialized it to false, but in the condition that the user failed to use the input values of 1 or 2 it gets set to true, which starts the whole process over of asking for values. Removing the boolean would break the code. You are trying to remove correct logic.

Comment: @cubicke.Jockey. ok thanks mate. if that possible that i show you my whole code?

Comment: I am on my way to bed so if this can wait till tomorrow then yeah I can take a look. I am PST. But I would advise you to give as much of the code you are having trouble with in your question so others can see it too.

I'll check back in my AM to see if you got helped and if not then I'll figure a way to contact you.